# In a JUnit Test, how can I assert two numbers are equal without considering their type?

Tags: java, junit

An example of what I want to do:

```
double delta = 0.000001d;
Number myNumber = resultOfSomeTestExecution();
Assert.assertEquals(5, myNumber, delta);
```

I want to assert that the result is 5, or at least nearly 5 within a reasonable delta interval, but I don't care whether it's an Integer, Long, Double, BigDecimal, or whatever. Is there an assertion library which can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `Number` instance has a `doubleValue()` method, which you can apply to the result of the test execution.

```
double delta = 0.000001d;
Number myNumber = resultOfSomeTestExecution();
Assert.assertEquals(5, myNumber.doubleValue(), delta);
```

The `Number#doubleValue()` is a valid choice, because you don't lose precision when working with integer and floating-point numbers.

Comment: I suppose you mean comma, not a plus! In other case, code is invalid and utilized deprecated method.

Comment: I agree this works, a bit more library functionality would have been nice (such as displaying the concrete type of the number in the assertion failure message, etc.). But as it seems no such library exists, I don't have the time to write one right now...

Comment: By the way, if you compare integers and need best precision, you can use `Double.MIN_NORMAL` constant as a `delta`. Also it looks more compact (one line less).

Answer (score 1):

Use .doubleValue() on myNumber - it'll do the trick:

Assert.assertEquals(5, myNumber.doubleValue(), delta);